# Couldn't figure out how to access libc on installing honeyd

Tags: debian, libc, honeypot

i tried to install honeyd and i dont know what's the meaning of the last line

checking if we can access libc with /usr/lib/libc.so*... no

configure: error: Couldn't figure out how to access libc

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem while I was trying to compile honeyd on kali 1-x86-64. The problem is that honeyd can not find libc in specified path in configure file.

You can change path for libc in configure file or create a symbolic link to the relative libc.so in /usr/lib like this (for x86-64 architecture):

ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libc.so

Answer (score 0):

I found all path references to `libc.so` and changed them from `/lib` and `/usr/lib` to `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64`. It fixed my problem.